# Help on the derivation of Abel's Theorem using the wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, intuition

I'm finding it difficult to solve the first order differential equation in the proof to obtain the conclusion. I've solved 1st order ODE's before and not had problems and I feel really silly for not being able to do this. I know this is separable,  but I can't get the solution in the required form.

$$
\frac{{\rm d}W}{{\rm d}t} = -pW 
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the equation as

$$
\frac{{\rm d}W}{W} = -p {\rm d}t
$$

Integrate both sides

$$
\ln W = - \int_{x_0}^x p(t){\rm d}t + \tilde{C}
$$

take the exponential

$$
W = C\exp\left(- \int_{x_0}^x p(t){\rm d}t\right)
$$

where $C = e^{-\tilde{C}} : {\rm const}$

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an improvement of the answer by user caverac:
to avoid assuming that $W>0$ (which is required in that answer) multiply the equation $\frac {dW} {dt} +pW=0$ by the integrating factor $e^{\int_{x_0}^{x} p(t)\, dt}$ to get $\frac d {dt}  (We^{\int_{x_0}^{x} p(t)\, dt})=0$.  Hence $We^{\int_{x_0}^{x} p(t)\, dt}$ is a constant $c$ and $W=ce^{-\int_{x_0}^{x} p(t)\, dt}$. This avoids dividing by $W$ and taking logarithm of $W$.

Comment: Certainly an improvement (+1)